# How can I disable relative dates in elements index?

Tags: control-panel

In control panel, specifically when displaying elements table under any section, postDate and expiryDate values are in relative format i.e. Today, Yesterday, Monday, Wednesday, ..etc.

How can I disable that and display them in dates only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until this feature get implemented, I think I'll go with the following workaround that I'm using right now.
It's based on  [getEntryTableAttributeHtml](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml) hook where I reformat the date value to match the user locale preferences.

```php
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute == 'postDate')
    {
        $localeData = craft()->i18n->getLocaleData(craft()->language);
        $dateFormatter = $localeData->getDateFormatter();
        $format = $dateFormatter->getDatepickerPhpFormat();
        return ($entry->postDate ? $entry->postDate->format($format) : '');
    }
}
```

or simply

```php
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute == 'postDate')
    {
        return $entry->postDate;
    }
}
```

which will return the date in Y-m-d format regardless of locale.

Answer (score 1):

Currently not possible as it's hard-coded into Craft.

Probably worth adding as a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com), though!