# Can control panel date display always be numeric?

Tags: control-panel, config, postdate, configuration

I understand the display of entries' postDate, etc., in the control panel can be localized, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get rid of the "yesterday" and "today" designators, and force displaying to always be M/DD/YYYY instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable relative dates in elements index?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/how-can-i-disable-relative-dates-in-elements-index)

Comment: Unfortunately, not really, as I don't want to use a plug-in to accomplish this.